# AWS resources with longer IDs and knife ec2 server create

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, aws-sdk, chef-recipe

I changed on AWS Resource ID length management the resources on my account to support longer IDs (reservation, instance, volume, snapshot).
Newly created instances from AWS console recieved the longer ID, but when I created a new instance with knife ec2 server create, the instance goes up with shorter ID like before.

```
"knife ec2 server create -N $NAME -r $RUNLIST -S $KEYPAIR --subnet $SUBNETID -E $ENV -Z $AVAILABILITYZONE --region $REGION --security-group-id $SECGROUP --bootstrap-version 11.8.2"

#gem list 'knife-ec2'
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
knife-ec2 (0.13.0, 0.12.0)
```

Is anyone have idea why ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you changed the setting as an IAM user, the chance will only apply to that user. If you change it with an IAM role, or the root account, it will apply to the entire account.